# "Empty response received" when using HTTPS

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a Facebook app that has been working with HTTP and HTTPS for some time. Recently - about a week ago I think - HTTPS stopped working. It now gives a 'Empty response received.' message every single time.

My server *DOES* have an SSL cert and HTTPS works on the server. It is not a commercial cert though, it is self-signed.

I know HTTPS is going to be a requirement in October... does anyone know:

1) What might be causing the empty response errors, and

2) What the requirements are for an acceptable SSL cert, according to Facebook? Self-signed no longer seems to cut it...

Comment: Are you receiving this error when you make an API call? Or when you try to load the app in an FB canvas?

Comment: Any page load presents the user with the empty response message over HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been noticing the same problem for the last few weeks as well.   Here's what I've been able to learn, maybe this will help you.

The problem seems to be intermittent, it happens at some times of day and not others.  Sometimes it happens only for some users.  I had setup a test page that just says Hello World in HTML and nothing else, and I still get the error.  I checked my access logs and facebook isn't hitting even hitting my server.

I am using Canvas.  I had set my Canvas URL to https://.  When I changed this to http://, the problem went away.  I had set my Secure Canvas URL to https://, and still got this problem.  I blanked this out since it was giving the error.

Another thing - check the HTTP status code that is returned by your canvas page - make sure it is 200.  At one point, we were redirecting http to https which returned a 302 status and facebook didn't like that and gave this error.

Comment: I have just picked up and installed a certificate from GoDaddy ($13/year) and on first blush, it seems to have resolved my problem. I will post a confirmation in a day or so and let folks know the final result.

Comment: Looks like it's confirmed... every HTTPS page load has worked since using the GoDaddy cert.

Comment: Switching to the GoDaddy certificate also fixed my issue -- I guess self-signed certs are no longer being accepted by Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

A self signed certificate is not adequate for presentation to an end user. Even if facebook "allowed" it, the users browser would show a security exception first. Godaddy has very inexpensive SSL certificates.

Comment: Agreed, but Facebook doesn't do things like a 'normal' website. Although no end user would trust my cert, they didn't need to... End users only saw Facebook's cert for apps.facebook.com, which is trusted. Facebook's back-end was loading my page over SSL and so they (Facebook, not the end user) needed to accept my cert. That was working fine previously, but some change has broken it. I'm just trying to figure out what the change was.

Comment: If your app is an IFRAME, your end users will get a security exception.

Comment: True, but this page is not an IFRAME. As a standard FBML app, the web page is loaded from my server by Facebook, parsed and then presented back to the user. As far as the browser is concerned, it's coming from apps.facebook.com, and has a matching certificate. It's not an issue of trust between the user's browser and the site, but (I suspect) between Facebook and my site.

Comment: FB may be getting the security exception since it can't find the trusted root CA (given that it's self signed), so it may be discarding the response or just not proceeding. I think a better question may be "who are trusted root CAs for FB?" to get a better idea of the end state you'll need to have.

Answer (score 0):

My SSL certificate had expired. I've just regenerated a new one and put it in place. It make take a while for the old cert to time out of Facebook's cache, but things are already looking better. Pages now load over HTTPS, though I'll hold off calling it a 'success' for a bit longer.

Comment: Well, that was short lived. The problem has returned, so I'm no longer convinced it is directly related to my certificate. I will update as I learn more.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. HTTPS works fine for iframe apps but not for FBML apps. If I use https and request for a FBML app - facebook doesn't even send a request to the CBURL (my server). On the browser end it just says "Empty response received". But the very same FBML app works fine for HTTP.

I'm using a GoDaddy certificate in my server and the same certificate is used for iframe apps - it works fine with iframe apps.